# How to change window borders to DDE

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I am very new to Linux, now I started using Ubuntu 17.04 and since I didn't like the Unity UI I decided to test out some desktop environments.

First I tested gnome, and I didn't like it either, so I went DDE and wow, it looks beautiful and also very functional.

So I decided to stick with it, however the window frames are still displaying like pure gnome and not following the DDE interface:

[image]

The first thing that came in my mind was to remove gnome desktop installation in order to things restore themself. So I runned `sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, and now I can't choose the gnome desktop enviroment on session startup, but still the frames are there.

So my question is, how can I make my window frames follow the same UI patterns than the rest of my system?

Running `apt list --installed` prints some packages with gnome prefix, should I remove them?

```
gnome-accessibility-themes/zesty,zesty,now 3.22.3-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-backgrounds/zesty,zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed,auto-removable]
gnome-bluetooth/zesty,now 3.20.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-calculator/zesty,now 1:3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-calendar/zesty-updates,now 3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-contacts/zesty,now 3.22.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
gnome-control-center/zesty-updates,now 1:3.24.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-control-center-data/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 1:3.24.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-desktop3-data/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-disk-utility/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-font-viewer/zesty,now 3.23.91-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-keyring/zesty,now 3.20.0-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-mahjongg/zesty,now 1:3.22.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-menus/zesty,now 3.13.3-6ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-mines/zesty,now 1:3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-online-accounts/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-orca/zesty,zesty,now 3.22.2-2ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-power-manager/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-screensaver/zesty,now 3.6.1-7ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-screenshot/zesty,now 3.22.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-session/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-session-bin/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-session-canberra/zesty,now 0.30-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-session-common/zesty,zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-settings-daemon/zesty-updates,now 3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-settings-daemon-schemas/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-common/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-software/zesty-updates,now 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-software-common/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.5 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-software-plugin-flatpak/zesty-updates,now 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-software-plugin-snap/zesty-updates,now 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-sudoku/zesty,now 1:3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-sushi/zesty,now 3.23.91-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-system-log/zesty,now 3.9.90-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-system-monitor/zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-terminal/zesty,now 3.20.2-1ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
gnome-terminal-data/zesty,zesty,now 3.20.2-1ubuntu8 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-themes-standard-data/zesty,zesty,now 3.22.3-1ubuntu1 all [installed,auto-removable]
gnome-tweak-tool/zesty-updates,zesty-updates,now 3.24.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
gnome-user-guide/zesty,zesty,now 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-user-share/zesty,now 3.14.2-2ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-video-effects/zesty,zesty,now 0.4.1-3ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Check out the Tweak tool, there should be an option to choose a different GTK theme. If DDE has a GTK theme then it should be available in the Tweak tool.

Comment: How do I install it?

Comment: *apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool* and launch it as *Tweak Tool*

Comment: Cant find it on my applications but managed to run it using terminal, but got this error at startup `Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available`. 

Also, changes I make there dont reflect on my enviroment :(

Comment: added some more info to my question

Comment: Did you open new windows after making the changes?

Comment: Oh, sure, yea I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64321/discussion-between-userdepth-and-marcos-j-c-kichel).

Comment: What is DDE? Do you mean KDE?

Comment: Deepin Desktop Environment https://www.deepin.org/en/dde/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Noobslab PPA for themes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deepin-gtk-theme
```

Open system settings in the control panel, then click on "Advanced settings"

[image]

Sources:

[Blog](https://soberanolinux.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/como-instalar-o-tema-e-os-icones-do.html)

[Guide](http://linuxdeepin.shendu.com/use/3)